# how to run a cmd.exe batch file in a sub shell

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a batch file that I usually invoke like this:

```
 longjob.cmd >result.txt 2>&1
```

This works fine, but the script changes directory during its execution leaving my shell in that directory - which is a nuisance.

Is there a way to run the command within a sub-shell - while still allowing the output to be captured ?

I have tried

```
cmd longjob.cmd >result.txt 2>&1
```

which just sits waiting for an exit command.

Also I tried

```
start longjob.cmd >result.txt 2>&1
```

which does run the script, but in a new window and all output is sent to that window instead of the file.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this is actually to fix the batch file. `pushd`/`popd` are of help here. Unless the batch file's purpose is to change the directory I'd never write one that leaves in another directory than the one it started in.

Comment: What about cancelling the batch file with ^C, for example. Is there any sensible way to restore the original working directory despite the batch file being cancelled?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
CMD /C longjob.cmd >result.txt 2>&1
```

Not sure how it'll deal with the redirection, but CMD /C lets you tell CMD what to run and that it should exit when done. (CMD /K lets you tell it to run something but stick around when done.) It will re-use the existing console window if run within one.

Comment: Exactly the opposite, Leo: `/c` exists after running the command, `/k` will give you the prompt afterwards.

Comment: Yep, I got the C and K the wrong way around. Edited to correct.

Answer (score 2):

The **[`call`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true)** command might be what you want.

i.e.

```
call longjob.cmd >result.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: if longjob.cmd calls chdir, the calling shell is left in that directory when the script ends when used with call.

Comment: Call does not appear to run the script in a separate process (sub-shell). It just executes the script in the current process leaving side-effects (directory changes, environment variable modification, etc.) from execution.